# ping localhost working, but ping http://localhost does not. And localhost not working on browser on OS X

Tags: localhost, osx-yosemite

Here, "ping localhost" works fine, but "ping http://localhost" does not. It says: "ping: cannot resolve http://127.0.0.1: Unknown host"

And on typing localhost on the browser, it says "failed to connect". Can anyone help me with this problem ?

/etc/hosts content :

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

Ping always works with an IP address.  Localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1,  however http:// does not resolve to  a IP, as it is a protocol, not the part of a host.

so http://localhost,  resolves to http://127.0.0.1,  which is not a host on the network